# Angular property binding - extract or not to extract?

Tags: angular, properties, binding

Let's say I have a certain page with the following codes:

"Pure" HTML:

```
<img [src]="urlParams.includes('search') ? 'search-icon' : urlParams.includes('detail') ? 'detail-icon' : 'empty-icon'"/>

<div *ngIf="(a && b) || (!a && c && d) "> ... </div>
```

I decide that I want to have a more cleaner html file, and move some logic to the control files, like this:

HTML:

```
<img [src]="decideParameter(urlParams)"/>
<div *ngIf="decideExpression(a,b,c,d)"></div>
```

AND in the corresponding control .ts file:

```
 decideParameter(urlParams: any) {
    if (urlParams.includes('search')) {
      return "search-icon";
    }
    if (urlParams.includes('detail')) {
      return "detail-icon";
    }
    return "empty-icon";
  }

  decideExpression(a, b, c, d){
    return (a && b) || (!a && c && d);
  }
```

My code sometimes contains even more complex conditions, which will be sometimes bound to properties, that changes a lot. These properties and variables sometimes from *ngFor even. In that case, what method is the better? To extract these expressions to the control file, or leave it in the html?

As I was wondering this, I noticed, that if I extract these codes, and insert a console.log to the extracted classes like this:

```
 decideExpression(a, b, c, d){
    console.log("method called!")

    return (a && b) || (!a && c && d);
  }
```

I can see that it is called on every mouse movement: 
[image]

So my question is:
Does extracting property binding expressions from the HTML to .ts methods generate more update checks? (Or, does it update already that much anyway?)

Comment: No it doesnt, it does the exact same amount of checking, one on each rendering. And Angular does a rendering after each asynchronous event, as XHR event, keyboard events, mouse events etc.. It was already the case before your refactor

Comment: Can you answer this instead of a comment please? (just so I can accept it)

Also, I suspect as much, but can you maybe back this up somehow with any source or reference maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't, it does the exact same amount of checking, one on each rendering. And Angular does a rendering after each asynchronous event, as XHR event, keyboard events, mouse events etc.. It was already the case before your refactor

If you want some details about expressions in a template you can check this [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-guidelines)